# How can I disable the guard during authentication on Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

This is what I have inside RegisterUsers.php, which is in my vendor folder:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    //$this->guard()->logout();

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

In my RegisterController, from the auth folder I have the following:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    Session::flash('status', 'Please verify your email for account activation');
    //if $request->role_id == '2' then save the role_id
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'verifytoken' => Str::random(40),
        'role_id' => $data['role_id']
    ]);
    $thisUser = User::findOrFail($user->id);
    $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
    return $user;
}
```

I deployed my site with forge but I just noticed that my registration does not work the same as it does on localhost.

When a user registers, the system automatically logs him in. On localhost, I had disabled the guard, but that is in the vendor folder.

Since I cannot upload the vendor folder, how exactly can I disable the guard on the live environment?

Comment: You don't need to update the vendor folder, the code you posted is inside the `RegisterController` so it should work, can you explain more?

Comment: @utdev I edited my question.
The code had pasted is not inside the RegisterController

Comment: hm ok and why can't you update the file inside the vendor folder? And which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Actually it works now. I ran the composer install command to add the vendor folder and edtied the RegistersUsers.php

Comment: Nice but check my answer below its a better approach its not a good practice to change the vendor classes, my answer provides a solution in which you don't need to override the vendor file

Answer (score 0):

You can override the register method. The `Auth\RegisterController:` uses `RegistersUsers;` from your vendor.

So you can simply create a method like this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```